# Definition of algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying John Voight's [Quaternion Algebras](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030566920)  book. This statements is "A homomorphism of $F$-algebras is a ring homomorphism which restricts to the
identity on $F$.". And then I'm trying to show this definition of algebra homomorphism equivalence with its definition of Atiyah-Macdonald's commutative algebra book. I don't still finish it. Please see it and help me.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Also nevermind. The book is open access.

Comment: John Voight defines algebras specifically over fields. In this case the maps $f,g$ must be injective, so you can think of them as inclusions. (in other words, if $A$ is an algebra over a field $F$ then you can think of $F$ as a subring of $A$). If you think like this then the two definitions are really the same.